# How to increment a value with using link_to_add in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to display the value `index + 1` when clicked `link_to_add` ("Add day" button).

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'schedule_form', f: f %>
      <%= f.link_to_add "Add day", :rooms, data: {target: '#room'}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= f.submit "Edit my schedule", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_schedule_form_html.erb**

```
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
<div id="room">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |a| %>
    <p><b>Day&nbsp;<%= a.index.to_i + 1 %></b></p>
    <%= a.input :room %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I clicked `link_to_add`, `Day 1` is always displayed.

Is it possible to increment index when I click `link_to_add`?
Or it would be appreciated if you could give me another solutions.

**SOLVED!**

**edit.html.erb**

add javascript.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'schedule_form', f: f %>
      <%= f.link_to_add "Add day", :rooms, data: {target: '#room'}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= f.submit "Edit my schedule", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function() {
        var count = $('.day-number-element-selector').length;
        //alert(count)
        $('.day-number-element-selector').last().html(count).prepend("Day ").wrap("<b></b>");
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_schedule_form_html.erb**

add class="day-number-element-selector".

```
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
<div id="room">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |a| %>
    <p class="day-number-element-selector"><b>Day&nbsp;<%= a.index.to_i + 1 %></b></p>
    <%= a.input :room %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested form sends up a blueprint of the element that you specified with `data-target`, and the rest is handled by the client. There are [these](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#javascript-events) handy events triggered every time you add or remove objects. So you could use javascript, something like this:

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function() {
  count = $('day-number-element-selector').length;
  $('day-number-element-selector').last().html(count);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Petr Gazarov. It works! I add what I did at the bottom of my question.